# Socket.io infinite reloading of the page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sockets, socket.io

This is my routes/index.js file.

I have set time in minutes and want to render it in my bookings.ejs file but it doesn't render.

The line after io.on doesn't get executed I don't know the reason why and webpage goes on infinite reloading the webpage.

How do I fix this issue?

Any help appreciated.

```
router.post('/bookspot', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  var id = req.body.id;
  var firstname = req.body.firstname;
  var email = req.body.email;
  var userEmailWhoBooked = req.body.userEmailInSession;
  var userFirstNameWhoBooked = req.body.userFirstNameInSession;
  var vno = req.body.vno;
  var time = req.body.time;
  var timeflag = req.body.timeflag;
  var area = req.body.area;
  let io = req.app.io;
  console.log('io ',io)
  if (req.user.email == email) {
    req.flash('error_msg', 'Cannot book your own spot');
    res.redirect('/spots');
  } else {
    var newBooking = new Booking({
      firstname: firstname,
      userEmailWhoBooked: userEmailWhoBooked,
      userFirstNameWhoBooked: userFirstNameWhoBooked,
      email: email,
      vno: vno,
      timeflag: timeflag,
      time: time,
      area: area,
      createdAt: Date.now()
    });
    newBooking.save().then((booking) => {
      
      Spot.findOne({
        _id: id
      }).then((spot) => {
        spot.capacity = spot.capacity - 1;
        spot.save().then();
      })

      //Time Logic
      if (timeflag == 'hr') {
        var hrtoms = time * 60 * 60 * 1000;

        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log('haiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii');
          console.log(booking._id);
  Booking.findOne({
    _id: booking._id
  }).then((booking) => {
    Spot.findOne({
      firstname: booking.firstname
    }).then((spot) => {
      console.log(spot);
      spot.capacity = spot.capacity + 1;
      spot.save().then();
      console.log(spot.capacity);
    })

    Booking.findByIdAndRemove(booking._id).then();
  })
        }, hrtoms)
      } else {
        console.log('helooooooooooooooooooooooooo!')
        //The lines below this doesn't get executed and page goes into infinite reload?
        io.on('connection', (socket) => {
          console.log('hiiii');
          let currTime = moment().format('hh:mm:ss');
          const spotTime = moment().add(1, 'minutes').format('hh:mm:ss');
          console.log('currtime ',currTime);
          console.log('spot time ',spotTime);
          let tout =  setInterval(() => {
            let incTime = moment().add(1, 'seconds').format('hh:mm:ss');
            let timetoSend = {t1: incTime, t2: spotTime}
            socket.emit('timer', timetoSend)
            console.log('Inc time ', incTime);
            if(incTime === spotTime) {
              console.log('done');
              clearInterval(tout);
            }
          }, 1000);
        })
```

I have tried several methods but that doesn't help much.